# How to alter image pixels of a wild life bird?

Tags: sdl, c, pixel

Hello so I was hoping someone knew how to move or change color and position actual image pixels and could explain and show the code to do so.

I know how to write pixels on a surface or screen-surface

```
usigned int *ptr = static_cast <unsigned int *> (screen-pixels);

int offset = y * (screen->pitch / sizeof(unsigned int));

ptr[offset + x] = color;
```

But I don't know how to alter or manipulate a image pixel of a png image my thoughts on this was

How do I get the values and locations of pixels and what do I have to write to    make it happen?

Then how do I actually change the values or locations of those gotten pixels and how do I make that happen?

any ideas tip suggestions are also welcome!

```
  int main(int argc , char *argv[])
    {

        SDL_Surface *Screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(640,480,32,SDL_SWSURFACE);

        SDL_Surface *Image;

        Image = IMG_Load("image.png");

        bool done = false;

        SDL_Event event;

        while(!done)
        {

            SDL_FillRect(Screen,NULL,(0,0,0));

            SDL_BlitSurface(Image,NULL,Screen,NULL);

                while(SDL_PollEvent(&event))
                {

                    switch(event.type)
                    {

                            case SDL_QUIT:
                            return 0;
                            break;

                    }

                }

                SDL_Flip(Screen);

        }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Do you want to persist the changes in a png file to your hard drive?

Comment: just in the program or game but if you could show the code for doing it in a png file that would also be very cool to watch and see for that matter :)

Comment: Both `Screen` and `Image` are of type [SDL_Surface*](http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/SDL_Surface). You are probably able to access their pixel data in the same way. What is not working?

Comment: the idea and code to change the value and location of image pixels where do I start , what do I write, how do I understand it , technicality is something I like to stay away from as much as possible unless impossible otherwise , I'm crazy like that :D.

Comment: So, you want to retrieve a pixel color value by specifying a coordinate and also be able to modify it?

Comment: yep also the position of the pixel as well how do I modify that.

Answer (score 3):

I will assume you are reading a 32 bit [RGBA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGBA_color_space) surface, which means each pixel will have 8 bit for Red, 8 bit for Green, 8 bit for Blue and 8 bit for Alpha(transparency).

## Pixels indices:

Pixels are stored in an one-dimensional array, so you can't simply say `pixels[x][y]`.

As they are stored in order from left to right and from top to  bottom, determining an individual pixel's index in the array is as simples as `pixels[x + (w * y)]` where `w`is the surface's width, and `x` , `y` are the coordinates.

I suggest defining a helper function for that:

```
int get_pixel_index(int x, int y, int w)
{
    return w * y + x;
}
```

## Getting individual pixels:

Accessing a single pixel by specifying it coordinates (x,y) in the surface can be achieved with the following code:

```
int index = get_pixel_index(x, y, Image->w);
Uint32 *all_pixels = (Uint32*) Image->pixels; //Get all pixels from surface.
Uint32 pixel = pixels[index]; //Get specific pixel
```

We use `Uint32` because we are reading from  32 bit surface.

#### Reading pixel color information:

The `pixel` variable holds the color information for the requested pixel.

If you want to access the RGBA componnents indivudally you will need some [bit twiddling](http://iki.fi/sol/boolean.html) or the [SDL_GetRBA](http://www.libsdl.org/docs/html/sdlgetrgba.html) function:

```
SDL_GetRGBA(pixel, Image->format, &red, &green, &blue, &alpha);
```

## Setting pixels:

You can set a pixel color as easily as:

```
pixel = color;
```

Where `color` is a Uint8 representing a RGBA color.

Alternatively, you can use [SDL_MapRGBA](http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/SDL_MapRGBA) which let you specify color components individualy:

```
pixel = SDL_MapRGBA(Image->format, red, green, blue, alpha);
```